# Explanation of what a density plot is

Tags: density-function, histogram

I have been working with histograms so far. I understand what they show.
I am trying to understand what density plots are. In this [tutorial](https://www.quanthub.com/how-do-histograms-compare-to-density-plots-in-terms-of-what-they-show/) it says

> The curve (of the density plot)represents the proportion of the data
> in each range, rather than the frequency.
>
> the height of the curve (shows) the proportion of the data that falls into that range.

What does that mean in practical terms.
For example I have the following histogram

[image]

or similarly
[image]

Then I try to plot the density and I got

[image]

I know what the value in the bin [0,0.1] means. (how many values in that range appear in my data)
But what does the curve in there mean. "the proportion of data that falls into that range" What range? The curve is a value for each point, not a range...

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86094/what-is-a-density-function?rq=1 - does this help?

Comment: @AlexJ reading that question and answer it gives me the impression that density has to be always below 1.0 ("probabilities") and therefore the plot above is wrong?

Comment: Does the density plot values have to be always under 1.0?

Comment: Density is not probability. It can have any non-negative value. Only its integral i.e. the area under the density curve must be = 1.

Comment: @IgorF. so the last plot I show *is not* a density plot?

Comment: I don't know. What's the area under the curve?

Comment: @IgorF.Oh I see, What does the number for each X represent in simple terms?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/500788/169343

Comment: Your problem is that your understanding of the histogram is incorrect: it represents probability by means of *area* of bars, not their heights.  Adopting this perspective leads to an immediate and natural connection to density plots, which use the same graphical metaphor: area represents probability.  The plot you label "density" is not a correct density: its total area is only about $1/4$ rather than $1$ as it must be.

Comment: @KansaiRobot Re "*Does the density plot values have to be always under 1.0?*". If you type *density > 1* into the search bar, magic happens. A couple of clicks and you end up at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/can-a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-be-ok