# Is there a sigma-algebra for the parameter space in relation to the likelihood function?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, likelihood, sigma-algebra

The likelihood function, $L(\theta|x) = f(x|\theta)$, is sometimes mistaken to be a pdf. I have always thought that showing an example where
$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} L(\theta|x) d \theta = 1 $ does not hold would be enough to conclude that the likelihood function is not a pdf, and I have not given it much thought beyond that.

Recently, I read some posts 1) [What is the difference between "likelihood" and "probability"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/what-is-the-difference-between-likelihood-and-probability), 2) [What is the reason that a likelihood function is not a pdf?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31238/what-is-the-reason-that-a-likelihood-function-is-not-a-pdf), 3) [How to rigorously define the likelihood?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29682/how-to-rigorously-define-the-likelihood/29695#29695), and in the comments [to an answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/31241/311760) of 2) it is stated that

"The $\theta$ has not even a sense in general because there's not even a $\sigma$-field in the parameter space!"

Whereas I have no reason to doubt this, it is not obvious to me why it is true, probably because my familiarity with $\sigma$-algebras is limited to the one page in Casella & Berger's *Statistical Inference*, and the post [Why do we need sigma-algebras to define probability spaces?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199280/why-do-we-need-sigma-algebras-to-define-probability-spaces).

Since the comment is more than 10 years old, I gathered it would make sense to post it as a question. There are more recent discussions in the comments of [Intuition for why likelihood function sometimes *is* a PDF](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500311/intuition-for-why-likelihood-function-sometimes-is-a-pdf), not mentioning $\sigma$-algebra specifically, so perhaps there exists some other statement regarding the senselessness of $d\theta$ without involving $\sigma$-algebra, but I have a feeling they might be connected.

Comment: The issue isn't whether there might *exist* some sigma-algebra on the parameter space $\Theta$ (trivially, there always exist many sigma-algebras).  It's whether *a sigma algebra has been defined by the modeler or is naturally determined by the model* or its intended application.

Comment: @whuber Would it make sense to edit the question to "is there a naturally determined sigma-algebra...?" I guess the answer to that question is no ...

Comment: $\int_{\Theta} L(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta $ generally doesn't equal 1, but as long as it's not unbounded one should be able to define a normalizing constant. After all, the Gaussian integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-x^2) \mathrm{d}x$ only equals 1 when divided by $\sqrt{\pi}$, which then gives the normal density.

Comment: @Durden Yes, I'm well aware of that. But, as in the comment I've cited in my question, the $\sigma$-algebra question seem to precede the integration. From what I understand from whuber's comment, I believe that one is skipping a step (defining the $\sigma$-algebra) when directly going for the integration argument, even though it is very efficient, and also more accessible to most people not familiar with set theory.