# Finding the likelihood function of parameter vector

Tags: self-study, likelihood, exponential-distribution

I am trying to do an excerise on likelihood functions and score vectors and I am having some trouble extending it to parameter vectors. The question is stated below.

Suppose we have two independent samples: $X_{1}, ..., X_{n}$ are iid Exponential random variables with mean $θ_{1}$ and $Y_{1}, . . . , Y_{n}$ are iid Exponential random variables with mean $θ_{2}$.

Find the likelihood and log likelihood functions for the parameter vector $θ = (θ_{1}, θ_{2})^{T}. $

In this case would the likelihood function be $$\prod{θ e^{-θ x_{i}} = θ ^ne^{-θ\sum x_{i}}}$$ (same as one with one parameter)? Or would it be the product of the two functions as shown below: $$\prod{θ_{1} e^{-θ_{1} x_{i}} θ_{2}e^{-θ_{2}y_{i}} = θ_{1} ^ne^{-θ_{1}\sum x_{i}}} θ_{2}^{n}e^{-θ_{2}\sum y_{i}}$$

Or would it be something different?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a Bayesian question?  If it is then you may need to provide a prior to update with your observations.  If not, then the parameters are what they are (albeit unknown) and do not have a pdf

Comment: This is not a Bayesian question. In this case, do you know how I would be able to determine the likelihood functions for the parameter vector?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Are you asking about the pdf of the data given the parameters? You may be interested in [What is the reason that a likelihood function is not a pdf?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31238/what-is-the-reason-that-a-likelihood-function-is-not-a-pdf). Otherwise, Henry is right—you'd need a prior.

Comment: I think that I may be asking the wrong question here. My final goal is to find a likelihood function for the parameter vector and I assumed that a pdf would be required to do so.

Comment: Part of the confusion may be that you have not explicitly stated what you are trying to do. Are you testing $H_0: \theta_1 = \theta_2$ against $H_a: \theta_1 \ne \theta_2.$ Are you seeking a 95% Ci for $\theta_1 - \theta_2.$ Both of these? Something else entirely?

Comment: Are you looking for _the likelihood of the parameters_? You've assumed an exponential distribution; its likelihood function can be looked up.

Comment: Ok, you’ve changed the question enough to be answerable—thanks! Why do you think the likelihood function would exclude the $y$s and $\theta_2$, as in your first equation?

Comment: Thanks for replying again! I don't think it should exclude the $y$s and $θ_2$ but the textbook I'm reading is slightly confusing and made it seem that it would use the same function