# The concept and notation about MLE(Likelihood) and MAP

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, conditional-probability

In generally, we say that X1, X2, ..., Xi are from a certain distribution, which can be represented by f(x;θ), where θ is an unknown parameter.

[image]

When I read content related to MLE or the Likelihood function, I often see the use of f(x|θ) to represent the distribution of data X1, X2, ..., Xi.

[image]

In Frequentist, θ is an unknown parameter, **not a random variable**.

1. Is f(x;θ) the same as f(x|θ)?
2. Is f(x|θ) a conditional probability even if **θ is not a random variable**? and why?

**In Bayesian, the theta is a random variable, not an unknown parameter**, the formula is:

[image]

with P is distribution like f.

3. Why P(x|θ) is likelihood? (θ is **random variable!**)
4. If we fix θ to an unknown parameter, i.e. P(θ=θ*), is MAP equal to MLE?

Comment: Short answer: $p(x|\theta)$ is the joint probability of $x$ before you sample and known $\theta$, but it is the likelihood when you know $x$ (i.e., your sample) but don't know $\theta$. They're the same expression, only once taken as a function of $x$ (while $\theta$ is fixed) and once as a function of $\theta$ (while $x$ is fixed). Most of your other questions are [answered here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/31238).