# Why is this likelihood function equal to the noise PDF?

Tags: probability, multivariate-analysis, maximum-likelihood, gaussian-process, likelihood

My professor has this slide up here:

[image]

Here, $y$ is an observed signal. $H$ is a deterministic transformation, which is assumed known. $f$ is the original signal (which we dont know), and $w$ is random gaussian noise. We are trying to recover $f$.

I understand everything, except for, why $p(\mathbf{w})$ = $p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{f})$.

That is, I understand that the multidimensional noise PDF is given by the above expression.

But why is that expression, ALSO equal to the likelihood function, $\mathbf{y}$, given $\mathbf{f}$? I'm not seeing this...

Comment: Where does it say p(w)=Likelihoodfunction? The function p(y|f) is a conditional probability density.

Comment: @emcor What do you mean? p(w) = p(y|f) as seen above, and p(y|f) is the likelihood function as given [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zyxxv56v3niy9m5/Screenshot%202014-06-25%2013.40.25.png)

Comment: The likelihood is [a function of the parameters,](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2641), so notation like "$p(w)$" clearly does not refer to a likelihood. Unless a distribution is assumed for $f$, though, "$p(y|f)$" is not a conditional probability density, either: it merely refers to the probability density of $y$ as it depends on the parameters $f$.  By assuming $W=Y-Hf$ has a Gaussian distribution, all you have to do is plug $y-Hf$ into the formula for a (multivariate) Gaussian density. Fixing $y$, $H$, and $C_{ww}$, it becomes a function of $f$: in *that* sense it's a likelihood.

Comment: @whuber Yes, he is assuming that $y$, $H$ and $C_{ww}$ are known. ....soooo are you saying that ONLY if we assume those three entities are known and fixed, can we say that $P(y|f)$ is a likelihood function?... I find myself getting more confused. He is nonchalantly saying p(y|f) is a likelihood function. Are we saying he is mistaken?

Comment: @whuber What if I rephrase: Forget the nouns: Why is p(w) = p(y|f) in the above expression? I understand the expression itself, etc. But I do not get by what right, we can equate p(y|f) to p(w).

Comment: We have to do some careful interpreting because the notation is sloppy. Apparently the model is $Y=Hf+W$ where $W$ is a random vector-valued variable. This makes $Y$ a random variable, too. Given any value of $f$, any *realization* of $Y$, which is written $y$, corresponds to a realization $y-Hf$ of $W$. The probability density of that realization is given by the equation. The right hand side $\Lambda$ is a function of $(y,H,C_{ww},f)$. If you *assume* values for $H$ and $C_{ww}$, and are *given* the data $y$, $f$ remains the only variable and you can study how $\Lambda$ depends on $f$.

Comment: @whuber I have edited the question with further details from the background setup. Does that help us decipher what is meant here? (I am still digesting what you wrote, all the same).

Comment: Your edits support my suppositions about how to read the slide. The $f$ you are trying to recover plays the role of unknown parameters; everything else is either known or assumed. Thus the likelihood will be considered a function of $f$ and you will later find values of $f$ that make the likelihood as large as possible. You might go even further and deduce confidence limits for your estimates of $f$ by studying how the likelihood varies as you vary $f$ around its maximizing value. You might possibly even adopt a "prior distribution" for $f$, but that would not alter the present interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

$p(w)=p(y|f)$:

It is because of what is annotated in red on the slide, you have $w$ and $y$ linked as:

$w=y-Hf$

,so $p(w)=p(y-Hf)$ as well.

If $H$ and $f$ are held constant, $y$ is the only random variable which determines the probability:

$p(w)=p(y-Hf|f,H)=p(y|f)$.

I assume he omits $H$ because it is defined as constant anyways, so the probability is no longer dependent on $f$ neither on $H$.

He then correctly substitutes $'w=y-Hf'$ into the Gaussian density of $w$.

Comment: One point worth addressing is the potential confusion of data with random variables. If the right hand side is called a "likelihood," then "$y$" must refer to data (that is, a realization), not to a random variable.  Furthermore, if we accept that calling the RHS a likelihood was intentional, then we must emphasize its dependence on $f$ rather than dismiss it.

Comment: Thank you Emcor. FYI, I edited my question to give more details on the background setup. That said, unfortunately I still find myself somewhat puzzled by why, exactly, p(w) = p(y|f). Specifically, I am not sure why you are saying that f is held constant, when we are in fact trying to find it...

Comment: "Likelihood" is the density evaluated at a datapoint, which we have in p(w) as already clear. As we also have p(w)=p(y-Hf), it is a notational convention to write the parameter to be maximized in the Maximum Likelihood Function as $f(x|\theta)$. This convention might be confusing here.

Comment: Creatron, I believe you may be overthinking this. In a formula like $2-x^2$, $x$ has some definite but unknown value. Your circumstance is no different conceptually. You will estimate $f$ by maximizing the likelihood, just as you would consider varying the unknown $x$ to maximize $2-x^2$, even though the quantity $x$ refers to is whatever it is and that doesn't vary at all. For more about how the likelihood works I will refer you once more to the link I gave in an earlier comment: please read the thread at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2641.

Comment: @whuber Thanks whuber, let me study that link and digest.