# 3D plot of Akaike Information Criterion (AIC) for suitable ranges of Lˆ and k

Tags: data-visualization, model, aic, bic

Giving that Akaike Information Criterion (AIC) is as follow:

[image]

How can I Produce a 3D plot of AIC for suitable ranges of Lˆ and k.

In other words what could be a suitable ranges of L to try?

Moreover, what is the function of L^? I am struggling to find the equation to represent L^ so that I can plot it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\hat{L}$ is the value of the assumed likelihood function evaluated at $\hat{\theta}$, i.e. at its maximum value for the observed data. If our likelihood function is $L(\mathbf{X};\theta)$ then $\hat{L}=L(\mathbf{X};\hat{\theta})$.  $k$ is the number of model parameters being estimated.

For comparing 2 models, the one with lower AIC is preferred. Higher values of the log-likelihood imply lower values of the AIC, holding $k$ constant, while fewer model parameters also imply lower values of AIC, holding $\hat{L}$ constant. The idea is to reward higher likelihood and penalize each time you add a parameter to the model, as you are losing degrees of freedom.

Assuming you are intending to construct a 3-D plot using triplets (AIC,$\hat{L},k$) from various models you have estimated, I'm not sure the plot will give you much insight beyond simply looking at AIC. The problem with creating a surface (as mentioned in the answer from @Lucas Farias) is that $k$ alone does not tell us which regressors we are including. For example $y=a_0+a_1x+a_2z$ and $y=b_0+b_1w+b_2v$ both have $k=2$, but will yield different values of $\hat{L}$ and AIC.

Comment: Thanks dlnB for the clarification. In simple words, what do you suggest values to use to plot this 3D plot.

Answer (score 1):

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#Definition), for the specification you presented:

> Let $k$ be the number of estimated parameters in the model. Let
>   $\hat{L}$ be the maximum value of the function for the model.

While $k$ is always non-negative, the range and shape of the model likelihood function $\hat{L}$ is [different for each problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140463/can-the-likelihood-take-values-outside-of-the-range-0-1), since it depends on the densities and data you are working with.

For this reason, even if you can create the surface you want for different specifications of the *same* model, it's impossible to obtain an AIC surface that is representative for all types of models.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, but I feel that I got confused with your answer. Can you please explain more?

Comment: @Jan what didn't you understand?

Comment: Is it possible to plot a Surface of AIC in a 3D space base on L and k inputs? I want to plot it based on any suitable range of L and K just to get a feel of it. I know that K cannot be negative (since it denotes the parameters size) so I can choose a range from 1 to 60 for example. However, since L is different for each problem, what could be a reasonable range (even if it is hypothetical)?

Comment: @Jan it really depends on the problem, so why don't you just plot it for many different ranges suitable for *your* problem?