# Why does my multivariate normal have a density greater than 1 (log-likelihood greater than 0)?

Tags: probability, density-function, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am calculating the log-likelihood of multivariate Gaussian distribution.  I am getting a positive log-likelihood.

**Density function**

$$f(x_1,...,x_n)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n|\Sigma|}}\text{exp}{\{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^\text{T} \Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)\}}$$
where $|\Sigma|$ is positive definite.

**Log-likelihood**
$$\text{log}(L)= - \frac{1}{2}\text{log}(|\Sigma|) - \frac{1}{2} (x-\mu)^{-\text{T}} \Sigma ^{-1} (x-\mu) - \frac{n}{2}\text{log}(2\pi)$$

Suppose

```
x = [0.0000000 0.9411407 0.9971905 0.9987736 0.9988251]
```

Mean: $\mu=\vec{0}$

Covariance matrix: $\Sigma$,

```
K=
            [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]        [,5]
[1,] 0.842916377 0.61430825 0.2378030 0.04889546 0.005339994
[2,] 0.614308254 0.84291638 0.6143083 0.23780289 0.048895481
[3,] 0.237802952 0.61430825 0.8429164 0.61430817 0.237802952
[4,] 0.048895461 0.23780289 0.6143082 0.84291638 0.614308339
[5,] 0.005339994 0.04889548 0.2378030 0.61430834 0.842916377
```

covariance matrix is positive definite.  We can do Cholesky decomposition: chol(K)

Ignoring the last term in log-likelihood with $2\pi$, it's a normalizing constant.

Calculating log-likelihood,
First term: $- \frac{1}{2}(|\Sigma|)$=2.642797.
Second term: $(x-\mu)^{-\text{T}} \Sigma ^{-1} (x-\mu)$=-1.857256.
First + Second=0.7855412

Why is it positive 0.7855412?  Log-likelihood should be a negative number.
What is wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: In case it is not perfectly clear that the duplicate is the same question, please note that (1) a likelihood is, [by definition, a probability density;](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2641) and (2) a density exceeding $1$ is equivalent to its log being positive. BTW, your power of $1/\pi$ is too large, the power of $1/2$ is too small (it's wrong to ignore either), and you are missing a factor of $-1/2$ in the argument of the exponential: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution. So possibly your results in this particular case are due only to those errors.

Comment: Probability is between zero and one and the log of probability is always non-positive. Meanwhile, density is non-negative but can be above one; consequently, its log can be either positive or negative (or zero).

Comment: @whuber What do you mean by 1/$\pi$ is too large?  Which term are you referring to?  I should have typed power of 1/2, now added.  But, it's in there in my calculation in R.  Either way, I should not be seeing positive log-likelihood, why am I seeing it?

Comment: @RichardHardy So, it's ok to have log-likelihood to be greater than 0?  I am confused.

Comment: Your errors are still in your code (and they haven't entirely been fixed up in the formulas, either: your log density is not equal to the log of the density due to several mistakes). Make a careful comparison with the Wikipedia formula. And yes, a log-likelihood can be greater than $0$ (and often is), exactly as the duplicate thread explains.

Comment: @whuber Why is it ok to have density greater than 1 (log-like greater than 0)?  The thread does not give concrete examples where I can **see** it.

Comment: My argument: density refers to the probability of getting something (head in coin toss).  Multivariate normal has density less than 1, $0 \le p(x) \le 1$, for all x.  Likelihood is multiplying n densities, so, it's even smaller.  Taking log of likelihood should be negative.  I don't see anything wrong with my argument.

Comment: Are you actually linking to the duplicate? The question itself cites a concrete example on Wikipedia. I also posted an answer that starts off with two graphs of PDFs that exceed $1$. I can't think of anything more concrete than that!

Comment: @whuber Sorry, I didn't know you meant the link in the post.  I was looking at the links in the comment.