# Relation between: Likelihood, conditional probability and failure rate

Tags: conditional-probability, likelihood, hazard

Crosspost from [math.stacksexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2038718/relation-between-likelihood-conditional-probability-and-failure-rate). Though it might fit better here.

My question is about the possibility of showing equivalence between the hazard rate, the conditional probability (of failure) and a likelihood function.

---

**Dynamics:** Consider a coin that has $P(\boldsymbol{H})=p$ and $P(\boldsymbol{T})=1-p$ such that $P(H) + P(T) = 1$. The stochastic process $X(t)$ evolves according to this dynamic over time $t$ resulting in a series of $\boldsymbol{H}$ until at time $T$ it lands on tails $\boldsymbol{T}$ which ends the sequence.

---

**Definitions:**

- Consider $T$ a continuous random variable with density $f(t)$ and cumulative density $F(t)$.

1) **Hazard rate**: $\mu(t)=\frac{f(t)}{1-F(t)}$.

Aka. force of mortality, hazard function, failure rate, [see wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis). This can be larger than one.

2) **Conditional probability of failure:** $P(t<T\leq t+\triangle t|T\geq t)=\frac{P(t<T\leq t+\triangle t)\cap P(T>t)}{P(T>t)}\approx\mu(t)\triangle t$

Showing equivalence between 1) and 2) for $\triangle t\rightarrow0$ is easy. Again, see wiki. 2) is the *conditional probability of failure*, given that the unit worked up until time $t$.

3) **Likelihood function:** $\mathcal{L}(\theta|X)$.

Where $\theta$ is a parameter ($p$) and $X$ is the data observed (e.g. the series of H). E.g. assuming a fair coin we can write $\mathcal{L}(P(\boldsymbol{H})=0.5|\boldsymbol{HH})=P(\boldsymbol{HH}|P(\boldsymbol{H})=0.5)=0.25$. Or alternatively, $P(\boldsymbol{T}|\boldsymbol{HH})=1-P(\boldsymbol{HH}|P(\boldsymbol{H})=0.5)=0.75.$

---

**Questions:**

**q. 1**) Am I right in asserting that the likelihood function $\mathcal{L}(\theta|X)$ $is$ the complement to the conditional probability function  $P(t<T\leq t+\triangle t|T\geq t)$?

Exemplified as $P(\boldsymbol{T}|\boldsymbol{HH})=1-P(\boldsymbol{HH}|P(\boldsymbol{H})=0.5)=0.75.$

**q. 1.2**) If **q .1** is true, how is the likelihood function connected to the hazard rate function? Can they be shown to be equivalent?

**q. 1.3**) Intuitively, all conditional probabilities are purely multiplicative processes. Can we generally write this as $P(t<T\leq t+\triangle t|T\geq t) = 1-\prod^{t+\triangle t}_tP(\boldsymbol{H})_t$? E.g. as the *conditional* probability of realising another $\boldsymbol{H}$ decreases, the probability (and thus likelihood?) of realising $\boldsymbol{T}$ increases.

**q. 2**) Is it generally true, that if all conditional probablities are purely multiplicative processes of numbers between one and zero, they all decrease with some exponential rate $\lambda$?

Consider the **cumulative hazard rate**: $\varGamma=\int_0^t\mu(u)du=-log(1-F(t))$. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis).

**q. 2.1**) If **q. 2** is correct, and we can express the integral over hazard rate as the negative logarithm to the complement of the cdf $-log(1-F(t)$ (sometimes called the survival function), is this essentially the same as the conditional probability?

**q. 3**) How does the above relate to the notion of *sojourn time*? One can imagine $N$ states with $N$ different hazard rates. What is this problem generally called and how can I relate it to expected mean sojourn time? Intuitively, states with a high hazard rate will have lower sojorn time. Are these equivalent somehow?

**q. 4**) If anyone would care to relate this to a Markov Chain with absorbing states, they are most welcome. Especially I am interested in how the conditinal probability relates to the transition probabilities.

---

I realise these are a lot of questions. Any hints, partial answers or call for clarity is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is about the possibility of showing equivalence between
>   the hazard rate, the conditional probability (of failure) and a
>   likelihood function.

TLDR; There is no such equivalence.

[Likelihood](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms) is defined as

$$ \mathcal{L}(\theta \mid x_1,\dots,x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_\theta(x_i) $$

so it is a product of probability density functions evaluated at $x_i$ points, given some fixed value of parameter $\theta$.

So it has nothing to do with hazard rate, since [hazard rate](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/apr/section1/apr123.htm) is probability density function evaluated at $x_i$ point parametrized by $\theta$, divided by [survival function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function) evaluated at $x_i$ parametrized by $\theta$

$$ h(x_i) = \frac{f_\theta(x_i)}{1-F_\theta(x_i)} $$

Moreover, likelihood is [not a probability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/what-is-the-difference-between-likelihood-and-probability) and it is [not a conditional probability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224037/wikipedia-entry-on-likelihood-seems-ambiguous). It is a conditional probability only in Bayesian understanding of likelihood, i.e. if you assume that $\theta$ is a random variable.

Your understanding of conditional probability also seems to be wrong:

> Intuitively, all conditional probabilities are purely multiplicative
>   processes. [...] Is it generally true, that if all conditional
>   probablities are purely multiplicative processes of numbers between
>   one and zero, they all decrease with some exponential rate $\lambda$?

The answer is no. [Conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) is a relation between joint and individual probabilities

$$ P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} $$

So it is *not* a process, and it is *not* multiplicative. Moreover, multiplicative relation is a definition of [independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory))

$$ P(A \cap B) = P(A)\,P(B) $$

or equivalently

$$ P(A \mid B) = P(A) $$

Even if you are talking about a random process, then this is not true. To give an example, imagine a series of coin tosses, if they are independent, then probability of tossing head given that previous toss resulted in tails is simply a (unconditional) probability of tossing head.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! **1)** If, in the Bayesian sense (e.g. $\theta$ is a rv), the likelihood function *is* a conditional probability, does this link to the conditional probability of failure as defined in *2)*? **2)** Am I correct in asserting that (in a coin toss experiment) if $Pr(H)=0.5$ then the *conditional probability* (conditioned on two heads) is $Pr(H|HH)=0.5*0.5*0.5$? How is this not a multiplicative process? **3)** Is the folliwng statement true? Any process that multiplies numbers together between 0 and 1 will decay with some rate over time as $e^{-\lambda t}$?

Comment: 1) Obviously $\prod_i f(x_i) \ne \frac{f(x_i)}{1 - F(x_i)}$; 2) for i.i.d. coin tosses $P(A|B)=P(A)$, so the conditional probability is 0.5; and 3) is a different question, deserting it's own question rather a comment.