# On the relation between conditional distribution and likelihood

Tags: bayesian, likelihood

Suppose we are modelling our data using a r.v. $X$ with pdf $f_X$ that depends on the parameter $\theta$. Further, we assume the parameter is itself a random variable, with a prior pdf of $f_{\theta^{old}}$

Let the joint distribution of the two be denoted: $f_{X,\theta^{old}}$. And, let's denote the conditional distribution as $f_{X|\theta^{old}}$.  Let's denote the pdf of the posterior distribution as $f_{\theta^{new}}$.

Suppose we observe $X=x_0$.

We are told that:

$$f_{\theta^{new}}(\cdot) \propto \underbrace{L(\theta^{old} = \cdot; x_0)}_{likelihood}f_{\theta^{old}}(\cdot) \quad \ldots(\ast)$$

Now, using Bayes' theorem, we have:

$$f_{\theta^{new}}(\cdot) := f_{\theta^{old}|X=x_0}(\cdot) = \frac{\overbrace{f_{X|\theta^{old}}(x_0,\cdot)}^{conditional}f_{\theta^{old}}(\cdot)}{\int_{t}f_{X,\theta^{old}}(x_0, t) dt}$$

Which can also be written as:

$$f_{\theta^{new}}(\cdot) := \frac{1}{\int_{t}f_{X,\theta^{old}}(x_0, t) dt} \left(\frac{\overbrace{f_{X,\theta^{old}}(x_0, \cdot)}^{joint}}{\int_{x} f_{X,\theta^{old}}(x, \cdot)dx}\right)f_{\theta^{old}}(\cdot)$$

Now, in many textbooks, likelihood of a r.v. $X$ given an observation is taken to be the function got by treating the pdf as having variable parameters but fixed argument. If we consider a joint distribution over arguments and parameters like above, the likelihood, given observation $x_0$, appears to be this function:

$$ t \mapsto f_{X, \theta}(x_0, t)$$

So, in this case the constant of propotionality of $\ast$ is $=\int_{t}f_{X,\theta^{old}}(x_0, t) dt \int_{x} f_{X,\theta^{old}}(x, \cdot)dx$

But, in other places, the likelihood is taken to be the conditional probability of $X$ wrt $\theta$ with one argument fixed, viz:

$$ t \mapsto f_{X|\theta}(x_0, t)$$

In which case the constant of proportionality is simply the marginal distribution of $X$ evaluated at $x_0$

I'll be grateful if someone would clarify this situation.

*Added:* This problem doesn't arise in a frequentist context. There the likelihood function is unambiguous since it makes no sense to take a joint distribution of data and parameter or conditional distribution of the one over the other.

Comment: @Xi'an I didn't mean defined as a joint density but as a function with the form of the joint density with data=observation. For ex: DeGroot and Schervish. I think my confusion partly stems from how to parse the density of X, viz; P(X=x; \theta), whether as a conditional distribution of X at a fixed parameter value or as the marginalization of the joint dist. wrt parameter. Sorry if this is stupid. :(

Comment: The issue is that there is no joint distribution without introducing a prior distribution. The likelihood is the part carrying the information brought by the data in a Bayesian analysis.

Comment: See also: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224037/wikipedia-entry-on-likelihood-seems-ambiguous

Comment: @Xi'an So, the conditional distribution of X wrt parameter is what is foundational; whereas the joint distribution is then found by scaling it with the prior distribution of the parameter?

Comment: Yes, it can be interpreted that way, although non-Bayesian (Nayesians) would balk at the notion of a conditional distribution in $X$ since they do not see $\theta$ as random or endowed with an extra probability distribution.

Comment: @Xi'an Right. Thank you very much for clearing this up. I find the modelling the parameter with a r.v. very natural since the observed sample is what is given and our uncertainty (like in Poincare's essay) is about the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The point is moot as the likelihood is never defined as a joint distribution over observables and parameters.**

> *...in many textbooks, likelihood of a r.v. $X$ given an observation is*
>   *taken to be the function got by treating the pdf as having variable*
>   *parameters but fixed argument.*

The [traditional definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Definition) of the likelihood function is the density of the sample $X$, at the observed value of the sample $x$, taken as a function of the unknown parameter when this parameter $\theta$ varies over the range of the parameter space.

[image: Fisher, R.A. (1922). "On the mathematical foundations of theoretical statistics". Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society A. 222 (594–604): 309–368.]

*[excerpt from Fisher (1922)]*

> *If we consider a joint distribution over arguments and parameters like*
>   *above, the likelihood, given observation $x_0$, appears to be this*
>   *function: $$t↦f_{X,θ}(x_0,t)$$ So, in this case the constant of*
>   *proportionality of (∗) is* $$∫f_{X,θ^\text{old}}(x_0,t)\text{d}t∫f_{X,θ^\text{old}}(x,⋅)\text{d}x$$

This joint distribution $f_{X,\theta}$ is only meaningful in either a Bayesian or a fiducial setting, hence does not correspond to the meaning of a likelihood. (In the case of random effects and latent variables, the likelihood is the integral of a joint over the random effects or latent variables.) The function$$t↦f_{X,θ}(x_0,t)$$is then proportional to the posterior of $\theta$ given $x_0$ with normalising constant
$$\int f_{X,θ}(x_0,t)\text{d}t$$but one cannot use it as a *likelihood* since (*) involves the multiplication of $L(\theta^{old} = \cdot; x_0)$ by the prior $f_{\theta^{old}}$.

Answer (score 0):

I would offer this as a comment, but apparently I don't have the rep yet to comment.

I think that parameterizing time (outside of $\theta$) in the above makes things more complicated than necessary to understand - and perhaps the root of your confusion. Further, I don't think it is necessary to introduce notions of *old* and *new* data (and hence $\theta^{old}$ and $\theta^{new}$) as this seems to be a question about definitions of likelihood and marginal likelihood.  I will simplify notation a bit first to make it more intuitive.

If your question is about updating parameters in light of new data, then my answer is superfluous, but I don't think it is.

Would I be correct in asserting that your question is essentially:

*What is the difference between **likelihood of parameters $\theta$** given data, and the likelihood **likelihood of parameters $\theta,t$** given data?*

Consider some data $D$ and a model $m$, where $m$ is parameterised by $\theta$. The probability of the data or *likelihood of parameters* is $P(D\vert\theta,m)$, which is equivalent to your $t \mapsto f_{X|\theta}(x_0, t)$. However, in your formulation, $t$ is also a parameter that you must marginalise out as well when defining the *marginal likelihood*. For now, consider $t\in\theta$ and write the marginal likelihood **of the data** as

$P(D\vert m)=\int P(D\vert \theta ,m) P\theta\vert m)d\theta$.

where it is easy to see that adding another parameter (time, $t$) would require a double integral, such as yours above.

However, I think I might have misunderstood your question - hence my wish to simply comment.

Comment: Hi. There is no notion of 'time-indexing' in my question. Perhaps my use of 'old' and 'new' has mislead you. They are just an intuitive labelling for the two distributions of the parameter.