# Why can't we interpret likelihood as probability?

Tags: probability, likelihood, discrete-data

Something similar is asked here [What is the difference between "likelihood" and "probability"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/what-is-the-difference-between-likelihood-and-probability?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

My question is (despite all verbal explanation why it is not to be interpreted as probability): in discrete case I feel it can still be interpreted as probability as it is the product of probabilities of all data points.

So what is wrong if I do that?