# What is the likelihood function of the starting time of diffusion?

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, brownian-motion, diffusion

I need to find the likelihood that a set of molecules was instantaneously released at time $t_0$, say $t_0=0$.

**Toy System Example:**

Let $N$ be the set of molecules released from a specific point in a 3D environment. The released molecules diffuse in the environment according to the following:

$$ r[t] = r[t-1] + (\Delta r_1, \Delta r_2, \Delta r_3)$$
$$ \Delta r_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\, 2D\Delta t)$$
where $r[t]$, $r_i$, $D$, and $\Delta t$ are the location vector at time $t$, $i$-th component of the location vector, diffusion coefficient, and the time step, respectively.

If there is an absorbing spherical body at a distance $d$, the hitting rate of the molecules until time $t>0$ is:

$$ f_{hit}(t)= \frac{r_{bod}}{d+r_{bod}} \, \text{erfc}
\left( 
\frac{d}{\sqrt{4Dt}}
\right) $$
where $r_{bod}$ is the radius of the absorbing spherical body.

I need to estimate  $t_0$ using the information of $f_{hit}$.

So, I thought of using the optimal maximum likelihood technique. I am not very familiar with the maximum likelihood technique. As per this [article](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2641/221423), I have come up with this likelihood function.

$$L(\hat{t_0}|t) = \arg\max\limits_{t_0} f_{hit}(t|t_0)\\
=\prod f_{hit}(t|t_0)$$

But knowing that $t_0$ is not a parameter, this does not seem correct, right? I am really confused. How do I work around this to find $\hat{t_0}$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is the stepped differences $\Delta r_i$ for which you should be maximizing a zero-mean normal distribution (estimate the SD). This is just a function of $\Delta t$. There should be no reference to $t$ or $t_0$. $\hat{t}_0$ notationally makes no sense: (hat means estimate... why estimate $t_0$?). It is an epistemiological argument like the big bang... empirical data won't support it. You can project backward in time based on any distribution until you reach a theoretical point mass.

Comment: @AdamO I need to estimate the time at which the molecules were released based on the times at which they arrive. That is why I use the notation $\hat{t_0}$.

Comment: You miss my later point. It's an epistemiogic question. *any* distribution can be projected back to a theoretical point mass.

Comment: @AdamO Pardon me, but I do not understand what you mean by `any distribution can be projected back to a theoretical point mass`.