# There are 100 people in a room. What are the odds that the shortest person in the room is born in February?

Tags: distributions, odds

This is a follow up question to the previous "[There are 100 people in a room. What are the odds at least 1 person is born in January?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2670/odds-at-least-1-person-is-born-in-january?)"

Comment: Just replace 31 with 28 on non leap years and with 29 on leap years assuming it is know whether or not it is a leap years.  Otherwise use a weighted average multiplying the 28 day result by 3/4 and the 29 day result by 1/4.  In any case the results will be nearly the same.

Comment: I have located the shortest person and kicked all the others out of the room.  Can you now answer the question, "what is the chance the person in the room was born in February"?  If not, why not?  (There are many legitimate reasons to demur and expressing any of them would help us understand what you're trying to ask.)